# Meteor installs Cordova plugins on every launch

Tags: cordova, meteor

On every device launch via

```
meteor run ios-device
```

meteor needs to install cordova plugins. It's not a real issue, but it takes a lot of time and slows down developement heavily. I have to run it on the device via XCode quite often, because hot code push comes and goes like random. And if it works, it also takes like 30 seconds...

Any tips on how to speed this up?

I know that hot code push in browser is extremely fast, but for most parts, I cannot use it, since my app has a lot of Cordova related code. Oh, and before I forget it: Yes, I am doing this in my local wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in Meteor 1.3:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3992